# Iterating over and deleting from Hashtable in Java

Tags: java, iterator, hashtable

I have a Hashtable in Java and want to iterate over all the values in the table and delete a particular key-value pair while iterating.

How may this be done?

Comment: Same for HashMap and other maps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to use an explicit `java.util.Iterator` to iterate over the `Map`'s entry set rather than being able to use the enhanced For-loop syntax available in Java 6.  The following example iterates over a `Map` of `Integer`, `String` pairs, removing any entry whose `Integer` key is null or equals 0.

```
Map<Integer, String> map = ...

Iterator<Map.Entry<Integer, String>> it = map.entrySet().iterator();

while (it.hasNext()) {
  Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry = it.next();

  // Remove entry if key is null or equals 0.
  if (entry.getKey() == null || entry.getKey() == 0) {
    it.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: You can't have `null` keys in a `Hashtable`. That's what makes it different from a `Map`. Also, you're querying `Map.Entry getValue` in the above code, instead of `getKey`. You can't do `entry.getValue() == 0` because the values are of type `String`.

Comment: @polygenelubricants, Map is an interface that makes no restrictions on null. HashMap is a Map implementation that doesn't allow nulls.

Comment: I don't reference Hashtable in my code and would not use it anyway as it's superseded by HashMap (which **does** allow null keys and values).

Comment: BTW 2 downvotes?!  Seems like some people are stuck using JDK 1.1 collections or just don't bother reading the API definition of Map.

Comment: I mention `Hashtable` because that's what OP has. And @Steve, `HashMap` does allow nulls (http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html).

Comment: And @Adamski, people are downvoting because the code is wrong. You said your code is supposed to "remove entry if key is null or equals 0", but instead you query `entry.getValue()` (which is of `String` type) instead of `entry.getKey()` (which is of Integer type).

Comment: @poly: Fair point and thanks for pointing that out (corrected) but why not just add a comment to that effect rather than downvote (which doesn't help anyone)?

Comment: The first comment in this answer is mine, and it said exactly that. As for why people downvote instead of commenting, you have to ask them.

Comment: And by the way, the code is still wrong. `getValue()` returns a `String`. A string can't be compared to the number 0.

Comment: @Adamski Its end of 2023 and I still have to use Hashtable (due to legacy apps).

Answer (score 44):

You can use `Enumeration`:

```
Hashtable<Integer, String> table = ...

Enumeration<Integer> enumKey = table.keys();
while(enumKey.hasMoreElements()) {
    Integer key = enumKey.nextElement();
    String val = table.get(key);
    if(key==0 && val.equals("0"))
        table.remove(key);
}
```

Comment: Can we use Enumeration for HashMap as well?

Answer (score 7):

You can use a temporary deletion list:

```
List<String> keyList = new ArrayList<String>;

for(Map.Entry<String,String> entry : hashTable){
  if(entry.getValue().equals("delete")) // replace with your own check
    keyList.add(entry.getKey());
}

for(String key : keyList){
  hashTable.remove(key);
}
```

You can find more information about Hashtable methods in the [Java API](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: You can do this but it's not necessary to use an additional collection; It just makes things more complicated.

Answer (score 7):

So you know the key, value pair that you want to delete in advance? It's just much clearer to do this, then:

```
 table.delete(key);
 for (K key: table.keySet()) {
    // do whatever you need to do with the rest of the keys
 }
```

Comment: i only knew the value so this wont work.
Thanks though for looking