# Logic for the game hangman in java

Tags: java, logic

I have a question on how I can approach a situation. I am still fairly new to coding. For my class our teacher is having us make the classic game of hangman, and I am stuck on a situation. I am just curious to see if anyone can help me get the logic down for this situation.

The problem I am having is this:

```
 The secret word is: hangman
 Your progress: -------
 Wrong guesses:
 Guesses remaining: 10
 Number of words possible: 7359
 Guess a letter: e
```

How would you go about finding the number of possible words remaining? We are given a dictionary that we read in and get the number of words from that. Can pretty much use anything to solve it. The problem is every time you guess a character correct the list will shrink like this:

```
 The secret word is: hangman
 Your progress: -an--an
 Wrong guesses: eix
 Guesses remaining: 7
 Number of words possible: 3
 Guess a letter: g
```

Just hope you guys can give me some ideas!

Thanks!

Comment: How would you do it if you only had 15 words?

Comment: how is the dictionary being stored?

Comment: @ekcrisp I am storing it in a Hashtable

Comment: @BheshGurung I do not have any code. Just trying figure out the logic for the situation. On trying to get the Number of words Possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say that your dictionary words are stored in a collection of some sort - say, a `List<String>`. Let's also assume that you know how to build a string that represents the current guessing state (i.e. `"-an--an"` from your example).

All you need to do is writing a function like this:

```
static boolean checkMatch(String candidateWord, String currentGuess) {
    return ...;
}
```

Your function needs to implement this logic:

- If `candidateWord` and `currentGuess` have different lengths, return `false`. Otherwise,
- Check each letter of the `candidateWord` against the letter of the `currentGuess` in the same position
- If the letter of the `currentGuess` is a dash `'-'` or if it matches the letter of `candidateWord` in the same position, move on to the next letter
- Otherwise, return `false`
- Once you reach the end of the word, return `true`.

With this function in hand, you could take the current guess, check it against each dictionary word, and increment the count for each time the `checkMatch` returns `true`. This would give you the number of potential matches.

Comment: take a look at this (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351331/iterating-hashtable-in-java) example for iterating over a hash table. Inside of the while loop you should use your checkMatch function to see if the Hash Key can match the current guess

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thank you, that was close to the idea I had, but a lot simpler.

Answer (score 0):

A worst solution maybe using regex and go through each of the words after one valid guessing.

To make this a little bit better, maybe pruning a little using length() ...

---

Oh, keep a Set of current valid words. (so only shrinking the set instead of go through each word)