# Java: How to call a method from class from an enumeration of instanced objects?

Tags: java

I made several instances of objects in a hashtable and want to call a method from each of them.

I made a for that goes through an enumeration of the values retrieved from said hashtable, but I'm unsure how to actually call the method on each object.

```
for(Enumeration<Agent> AgentEnum = AgentList.elements(); AgentEnum.hasMoreElements();){
        //content+=
        AgentEnum.nextElement();
    }
```

Content should receive the return of the method I'm trying to call from class Agent.

Comment: What does `nextElement()` return?

Comment: Next element in the enumeration, if such an element exists. It's from java.util.Enumeration.

Comment: So it returns the next _object_ in the enumeration? How do you invoke a method on an _object_ (an object reference that is)?

Comment: Also, both `Hashtable` and `Enumeration` are not recommended. Use `Iterator` and `HashMap`.

Comment: I guess I'd use `values()` from `HashMap`, then?

Comment: See my answer, I added the use of `values()` directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate over the [keys](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#keys%28%29) in your hashmap. For example:

```
Enumeration<Agent> AgentEnum = AgentList.keys();
while(AgentEnum.hasMoreElements()) {
    Agent key = AgentEnum.nextElement();
    YOUR_CLASS value = AgentList.get(key);
    value.whatever();
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**

Or use the [values](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html#values%28%29) directly:

```
for(YOUR_CLASS obj : AgentList.values()) {
    obj.whatever();
    ...
}
```

Other methods are discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2351331/iterating-hashtable-in-java), for example.

Comment: And that's a bad advice. If the goal is to call a method on each *value* of a Map, the OP should iterate on the *values* of the map, not on its keys.

Comment: He's saying that enumeration goes through values, not keys.

Answer (score 0):

```
content = AgentEnum.nextElement().<your-method>();
```

Comment: I don't know what the <your-method> should return. From the example in the code it looks like the author wanted to accumulate the values that the method returns. I've changed += to =, but again if the author is trying to sum something for all objects, he'll need to put += back.